# Pandas problem with pivot: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I really don't understand

This dataframe only has three columns: `hostname`, `attribute`, `value`, `app`. I have filtered it to only have two attibutes `os` and `ip`, so it looks like:

```
hostname    attr   value   app
----------- ------ ------- ----------
host1       os     win10   app1
host1       ip     1.1.1.1 app1
host2       os     win10   app2
host2       ip     2.2.2.2 app2
host1       os     win10   app3
host1       ip     1.1.1.1 app3
...
```

Right now, I don't need the `app` column, so I dropped it:

```
df = df[['hostname', 'attr', 'value']]
```

...this of course creates duplicates, so before calling `pivot()`, I drop the duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

If ask for duplicates

```
df.loc[df.duplicated()]
```

of course I get an empty dataframe. No duplicates. So I do the `pivot()`

```
df.pivot(index='hostiname', columns='attr', values='value')
```

It throws `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

The dataframe has around 2,000 rows, so in my desperation I checked like:

```
df[0:200].pivot(index='hostiname', columns='attr', values='value')
```

And works as expected, so, if I keep until about row 239 it throws the error. I see row 239, of course I don't see anything wrong. So I simply don't get it. I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: check duplicated of hostiname and attr, this combination is not unique

Comment: but if I dropped the duplicates? why should there be duplicates?

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['hostname', 'attr'] ,inplace=True) ?

Comment: No, just drop_duplicates, I'll try that, thanks

Comment: It just worked. And I got it. When I was looking for dupes I was using `df.loc[df.duplicated()]` without the `keep=False` parameter, so I wasn't able to look at the duplicated rows ‍♂️. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yw :-) happy coding